# ¿Como sacar los 2 números mayores de un array con un do-while?

Tags: php, revisión-de-código, loops, depuración

Tengo un enunciado en el cual me dicen que debo generar un array escalar con 8 números aleatorios entre 10 y 100 obteniendo los dos mayores, sin usar la función `max()` y con  `do-while`.

Debe mostrarme el array por pantalla.

Mi código **PHP**:

```
<?php
//declaramos las variables
$arrayvalor = array();
$r = 0;
//hacemos el bucle do wile
do {
    $nurand = mt_rand(10, 100);

    if (!in_array($nurand,$arrayvalor)) {

        array_push($arrayvalor,$nurand);
        sort($arrayvalor);
        var_dump($arrayvalor);
        //ordenamos y mostramos
        $r++; 

} while ($r <= 8);
//mostramos el array
?>
```

Comment: es esto lo que quieres? [ver demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/559b0d1aaffbd137b6d2e8c45788a1bf0ac0f41f)

Comment: @ras212 puedes poner un ejemplo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** He edito la respuesta por que no he leído bien lo que necesitas:

[Ver Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d8508bfb23660c80f22111d2161536adde855541)

Explicación en los comentarios:

```
$arrayvalor = [];
$c          = 0;
// Iniciamos las variables para guardar los dos mayores números
$high_1 = $high_2 = 0;

do {

    $nurand = mt_rand(10, 100);

    if (!in_array($nurand, $arrayvalor)) {
        // Guardamos cada vuelta el numero generado
        $arrayvalor[$c] = $nurand;
    }

    // Comprobamos que el array no devuelva null
    if (isset($arrayvalor[$c])) {

        // Comprobamos y guardamos los dos mayores números

        // Comprobamos si el número del array es mayor que $high_1
        if ($arrayvalor[$c] > $high_1) {

             // Pasamos el mayor número al segundo $high_2
            $high_2 = $high_1;
            $high_1 = $arrayvalor[$c]; // Guardamos el mayor número a $high_1
        }
        // Comprobamos si el número del array es mayor que $high_2
        else if ($arrayvalor[$c] > $high_2) {

            $high_2 = $arrayvalor[$c];  // Guardamos el número a $high_2
        }
    }
    $c++;

} while ($c <= 8);

echo 'Mayor 1 = '.$high_1;
echo "\n";
echo 'Mayor 2 = '.$high_2;
echo "\n";
print_r($arrayvalor);
```

Answer (score 1):

Como la única limitación que tienes según tu pregunta es utilizar la función `max()`, puedes utilizar el siguiente código para introducir tus valores en el array:

```
<?php
    $arrayvalor = array();
    $c = 0;

    do {
        $nurand = mt_rand(10, 100);
        if (!in_array($nurand,$arrayvalor)) {
            array_push($arrayvalor,$nurand);
            $c++; 
        }
    }while ($c <= 8);
```

Una vez introducidos todos los valores puedes ordenarlos mediante la función [`sort()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.sort.php):

```
sort($arrayvalor);
```

Y para sacar todos los elementos del array por pantalla puedes utilizar [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.var-dump.php):

```
var_dump($arrayvalor);
```

Aunque también puedes usar la función [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.print-r.php):

```
print_r($arrayvalor);
```

E incluso mostrar cada uno de los elementos mediante la función [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.echo.php) y un bucle. Yo en este caso he elegido [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
foreach($arrayvalor as $valor){
    echo $valor . "\n";
}
```

Por último puedes acceder a la posición -1 y -2 del array (contando desde el final) ya que los arrays se empiezan a ordenar desde la posición 0. Para obtener la longitud del array puedes usar la función [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.count.php):

```
echo "Los valores máximos son".  $arrayvalor[count($arrayvalor) - 1] ." y " .$arrayvalor[count($arrayvalor) - 2];
```

El código completo quedaría:

```
<?php
    $arrayvalor = array();
    $c = 0;

     do {
        $nurand = mt_rand(10, 100);
        if (!in_array($nurand,$arrayvalor)) {
            array_push($arrayvalor,$nurand);
            $c++; 
        }
    } while ($c <= 8);

    sort($arrayvalor);
    var_dump($arrayvalor); //Muestro todo el array

    //Muestro los dos máximos valores
    echo "Los valores máximos son ".  $arrayvalor[count($arrayvalor) - 1] ." y " .$arrayvalor[count($arrayvalor) - 2];

?>
```

Y aquí tienes la **[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6e1b3e26e2a9d8b82efdb8c7ec1099ae6b43ff3a)**.

Comment: Para hacerlo con do while es igual?

Comment: @ras212 Sí, la única diferencia entre el bucle `while` y el bucle `do-while` es que en el bucle `while` se compara antes de entrar al bucle y en el bucle `do-while` se ejecuta el contenido del bucle y luego se compara. Sin embargo, para tu caso no afectaría.

Comment: Me da error: Este es mi código ```<?php
//declaramos las variables
    $arrayvalor = array();
    $r = 0;
//hacemos el bucle do wile
    do {
        $nurand = mt_rand(10, 100);
        if (!in_array($nurand,$arrayvalor)) {
            array_push($arrayvalor,$nurand);
            sort($arrayvalor);
            var_dump($arrayvalor);
            //ordenamos y mostramos
            $r++; 
    } while ($r <= 8);
    //mostramos el array
    ?>```

Comment: @ras212 Edita la pregunta con tu nuevo código, sin borrar el primer código. Simplemente haz un edit y ponlo al final de la pregunta.

Comment: el error es este Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /opt/lampp/htdocs/practicas/01practica.php on line 16

Comment: @ras212 ¿Has seguido todos mis pasos? Con mi código funciona. Ahora pongo el ejemplo completo como quedaría.

Comment: @ras212 He editado la respuesta con el código completo de lo que necesitarías.

Comment: @Error404: No hace falta ordenar el array, puedes localizar el max y min durante la creación del array, y es más eficiente: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e01697b2e05bef612c914636e96649dbc1353969

Comment: @zevane Como para todo, hay un montón de caminos para realizar una misma acción. Sin embargo, creo que de esta manera se veía mucho más claro. De todas formas, creo que te has confundido con el link ya que me lleva a esta pregunta.

Comment: @Error404: Acabo de editar el link, gracias. A mi me parece que, si te dicen que no uses max(), y usas sort(), estás haciendo trampa. Esto es para una práctica...

Comment: @zevane Realmente, si te fijas en su primer edit, había dentro del código una línea que era así: `sort numeric` por lo que supuse que había intentado usar esa función sin éxito. Si el OP hubiera especificado algo más sobre otras posibles funciones "prohibidas" o que lo debía hacer sí o sí de forma manual entonces hubiera cambiado la respuesta.

Comment: @Error404 Esto ya es para chat, pero... ¿realmente tú harías lo del sort si tuvieras que hacer eso en tu trabajo??